# row_number ranking function to filter the latest records in DF

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to apply a Window function to a `DataFrame` to get only the latest metrics for every Id. For the following data I expect the `df` to contain only the first two records after applying a Window function.

```
| id | metric | transaction_date |
| 1  | 0.5    |  05-10-2019      | 
| 2  | 15.9   |  07-22-2020      |
| 2  | 4.7    |  11-03-2017      |
```

Is it a correct approach to use `row_number` ranking function? My current implementation looks like this:

```
    df.withColumn(
        "_row_number",
        F.row_number().over(
            Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(F.desc("transaction_date")))
    )
    .filter(F.col("_row_number") == 1)
    .drop("_row_number")
```

Comment: `df.sort_values(by='transaction_date').groupby(by='id').head(-1)` Would this work for you?

Comment: I think `.head(-1)` will only give you one row. `.first()` will give the first row from each groupby.

Comment: This looks good and does what you want. Why do you think this is not correct approach?

Answer (score 1):

You need to first sort the dataframe by id and date (descending). Then you do group by id. The first method on group by object will return the first row (which has the latest date).

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,2], 
'metric':[0.5, 15.9, 4.7], 
'date':[datetime(2019,5,10), datetime(2020,7,22), datetime(2017,11,3)]})


## sort df by id and date
df = df.sort_values(['id','date'], ascending= [True, False])

## return the first row of each group
df.groupby('id').first()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  val fDF = Seq( (1, 0.5,  "05-10-2019"),
    (2, 15.9,  "07-22-2020"),
    (2, 4.7,  "11-03-2017"))
    .toDF("id", "metric", "transaction_date")

  val f1DF = fDF
    .withColumn("transaction_date", to_date('transaction_date, "MM-dd-yyyy"))
    .orderBy('id.asc,'transaction_date.desc)

  val f2DF = f1DF.groupBy("id")
    .agg(first('transaction_date).alias("transaction_date"),
      first('metric).alias("metric"))

  f2DF.show(false)
  //      +---+----------------+------+
  //      |id |transaction_date|metric|
  //      +---+----------------+------+
  //      |1  |2019-05-10      |0.5   |
  //      |2  |2020-07-22      |15.9  |
  //      +---+----------------+------+
```

Comment: first function is non-deterministic - This solution will give inconsistent results in cluster mode